# Solr Did you mean (Spell check component)

Tags: solr, autocorrect, spell-checking

I use solr for my apps and i integrated the spellcheck component but i have some problems :

First : 
When i type a term separated by space they give me the correction for each term

Eg : **"wat ters"** => **"what term"** but the true is **watters**

Second : 
When i type some phrase with some wrong term. although the other terms are correct they apply the spell for all terms.

Eg : "**Difreences** in **lankuage** use conventions"
 => "Differences in language use **conversions**".

The true is "Differences in language use conventions"

This is my config in **solrconfig.xml** :

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
            <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
            <lst name="spellchecker">
                <str name="name">default</str>
                <str name="field">spell</str>
                <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
            </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
            <lst name="defaults">
                <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
                <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
                <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
            </lst>
            <arr name="last-components">
                <str>spellcheck</str>
            </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**Schema.xml :**

Field type:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="multiterm" >
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
                <analyzer type="index">
                   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
                     <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
                     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
                </analyzer>
                <analyzer type="query">
                     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
                     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                     <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
                     <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
                     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
                </analyzer>
            </fieldType>
```

Fields :

```
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Copy Fields

```
<copyField source="title" dest="spell"/>
```

I would appreciate your help

Cheers

Comment: Nice question...do you have any tutorial that you used to learn more about lucene...other then the official documentation from Solr page? Ty

Comment: @Sebastian : 
**Basic Tutorial :** 

[Solr in 5 minutes](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html),
[Apache Lucene quick-start guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-apachelucene/).

**Advanced Tutorial :**
[Dzone Solr Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/links/search.html?query=solr+lucene&x=-1335&y=-4).


**Examples :**
[solr Drupal for Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr), 
[Apache Solr for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/solr-for-wordpress/),
[Solr Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.solr.php).

Good luck, i hope it helps ;)

Comment: **Books :**
[Lucene and Solr: The Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Lucene-Solr-Definitive-comprehensive-realtime/dp/1449359957/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1378896499&sr=1-3&keywords=solr),
[Apache Solr 4 Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/Apache-Solr-Cookbook-Rafal-Kuc/dp/1782161325/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1378896499&sr=1-1&keywords=solr).

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem you could use [WordBreakSpellChecker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2993)

As for your second problem you could set  `<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>` to `<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>` and see if this has the expected result.

Comment: Hi Klein, thnk's for your response, am using appach-solr3.5 to interact with php. Can you tell me how can i use this patch ? Cheers

Comment: Is WordBreakSpellChecker is standard in appach-solr3.5 ?

Comment: It's not standard. You need to apply it to source and build new jar/war.

Comment: Hi, I am a php coder on windows platforms so java development is new to me. can you tel me how to build the new jar/war on apach-solr
After search i found the spellCheckComponent.class file but there ise spellCheckComponent.java file

Comment: i opened the apache-solr-3.5.0.war that exist on the /dist path

Comment: Thank's very much Mr. Klein, i'll check it out and keep you informed. Cheers